# Copy chapters in MP4 input stream to output stream in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to copy two MP4 input streams into one output container and I'm having trouble maintaining the chapter indexes from both files into the output stream.

I have two files, specified by `streams.txt` which is in the correct format, that both contain an H.264 video stream, an AC-3 audio stream and an AAC audio stream, and am concatenating the two files using the following `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i streams.txt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 copy output.mp4
```

This correctly produces the output file that I want, with both files combined into an output file with all three streams. I am however having trouble adding the chapters from both input files into the output one. I understand that I'm supposed to use the `-map_metadata` option, but I'm having trouble with the format of it that doesn't produce the following error message:

```
Invalid chapter index 0 while processing metadata maps.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that ffmpeg doesn't currently support chapter concatenation for MP4 containers.

Comment: Did you you try `-map_chapters` in addition to `-map_metadata`? https://superuser.com/questions/1320389/updating-mp4-chapter-times-and-names-with-ffmpeg